# formatting batch output for database details

Tags: batch-file, formatting

set /p=%date% %ComputerName% C:\zz\aaa.rpt

"%BinPath%\psql.exe" -h %PGHOST% -p %PGPORT% -U %PGUSER% --dbname "%PGDATABASE%" --tuples-only --command="select datname as DB_name, pg_size_pretty(pg_database_size(datname)) as DB_size from pg_database where datname not in ('template0','template1');">>C:\zz\aaa.rpt

I am getting o/p :

Mon 05/24/2021 MY-PC postgres | 12 MB

abc | 13 MB

I want o/p as:

Mon 05/24/2021 MY-PC postgres | 12 MB

Mon 05/24/2021 MY-PC abc | 13 MB

Comment: You asked this question yesterday, and were provided with advice on how to achieve it. We are not going to do everything for you, we expect you to make an effort. Please follow that advice you were given.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you are looking for a constant output. You can use a shell environment variable in the postgresql query, like that :

```
echo[|set /p=> C:\zz\aaa.rpt
set "LOCALV_DATE_PC=%date% %ComputerName%"
"%BinPath%\psql.exe" -h %PGHOST% -p %PGPORT% -U %PGUSER% --dbname "%PGDATABASE%" --tuples-only
     --command="select '%LOCALV_DATE_PC%' as PC_ref, datname as DB_name, 
                       pg_size_pretty(pg_database_size(datname)) as DB_size 
                   from pg_database where datname not in ('template0','template1');">>C:\zz\aaa.rpt
```